# Write to NUnit's Text Output tab from unmanaged code

Tags: windows, logging, nunit, c++-cli, unmanaged

I have an NUnit test dll written in C++/CLI, which tests some unmanaged code. Is there a way to print log messages to NUnit's Text Output tab from the unmanaged code? I tried `OutputDebugString` and `cout << "blah"`, but no cigar.

NUnit version: 2.5.10

I know this might be bad practice, but let me do it just once, ok? :P

Comment: if it's C++/CLI maybe try logging using System::Diagnotics::Trace::TraceInformation?

Comment: I want to do it from the unmanaged code, which is in a separate, unmanaged dll

Comment: I see, I'm not sure either then, would have thought OutputDebugString would have done the trick in that case then.. just curious in that case if the messages show up in DebugView..http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647

Comment: I forgot to mention I'm using .NET 4.0, which [DebugView fails to work with](http://dommyzee.blogspot.com/2011/04/debug-and-trace-messages-not-showing-in.html). I'm such a lucky guy...

Comment: I'd do it with a callback into the managed code.

Comment: @dario_ramos : .NET 4 works just fine with DebugView; I was using that very combination earlier today (specifically with `Trace.WriteLine`).

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any way to my knowledge to capture this output in the output tab.

However, there is an undocumented option, `/console`, to the NUnit GUI runner that creates a separate console on which any unmanaged output to standard output is displayed. It may also capture standard error - I wrote it a long time ago and don't remember.

Comment: +1, didn't know of these options. They aren't totally undocumented; if you get it wrong a message box appears listing them. I just tried this and a console does appear, but I can't get any of my output to appear there. I tried using `cout`, `cerr` and `::OutputDebugString`. I tried directly in the C++/CLI test code, then in my unmanaged code. No cigar. If I have some time later I'll look into the NUnit code. Ah, forgot to say, I'm using NUnit 2.6.